# How to set a cell to NaN in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I'd like to replace bad values in a column of a dataframe by NaN's.

```
mydata = {'x' : [10, 50, 18, 32, 47, 20], 'y' : ['12', '11', 'N/A', '13', '15', 'N/A']}
df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)

df[df.y == 'N/A']['y'] = np.nan
```

Though, the last line fails and throws a warning because it's working on a copy of `df`. So, what's the correct way to handle this? I've seen many solutions with `iloc` or `ix` but here I need to use a boolean condition.

Comment: I feel like the title is misleading.  The problem isn't that you want NaN in your dataframe.  The problem is that you're "trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame".

Answer (score 196, accepted):

just use `replace`:

```
In [106]:
df.replace('N/A',np.NaN)

Out[106]:
    x    y
0  10   12
1  50   11
2  18  NaN
3  32   13
4  47   15
5  20  NaN
```

What you're trying is called chain indexing: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

You can use `loc` to ensure you operate on the original dF:

```
In [108]:
df.loc[df['y'] == 'N/A','y'] = np.nan
df

Out[108]:
    x    y
0  10   12
1  50   11
2  18  NaN
3  32   13
4  47   15
5  20  NaN
```

Comment: With this solution you have to import also numpy as np. By using pd.NA there is no need to import numpy.

Answer (score 51):

Most replies here above need to import an external module:
`import numpy as np`

There is a built-in solution into pandas itself: `pd.NA`, to use like this:

```
df.replace('N/A', pd.NA)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60115806/pd-na-vs-np-nan-for-pandas

Answer (score 19):

While using `replace` seems to solve the problem, I would like to propose an alternative. Problem with mix of numeric and some string values in the column not to have strings replaced with np.nan, but to make whole column proper. I would bet that original column most likely is of an object type

```
Name: y, dtype: object
```

What you really need is to make it a numeric column (it will have proper type and would be quite faster), with all non-numeric values replaced by NaN.

Thus, good conversion code would be

```
pd.to_numeric(df['y'], errors='coerce')
```

Specify `errors='coerce'` to force strings that can't be parsed to a numeric value to become NaN. Column type would be

```
Name: y, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 13):

As of pandas 1.0.0, you no longer need to use numpy to create null values in your dataframe. Instead you can just use pandas.NA (which is of type pandas._libs.missing.NAType), so it will be treated as null within the dataframe but will not be null outside dataframe context.

Comment: While this doesn't solve OP's problem, I upvoted because it actually answered the question in the title.

Answer (score 12):

You can use replace:

```
df['y'] = df['y'].replace({'N/A': np.nan})
```

Also be aware of the `inplace` parameter for `replace`. You can do something like:

```
df.replace({'N/A': np.nan}, inplace=True)
```

This will replace all instances in the df without creating a copy.

Similarly, if you run into other types of unknown values such as empty string or None value:

```
df['y'] = df['y'].replace({'': np.nan})

df['y'] = df['y'].replace({None: np.nan})
```

Reference: [Pandas Latest - Replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[df.y == 'N/A',['y']] = np.nan
```

This solve your problem. With the double [], you are working on a copy of the DataFrame. You have to specify exact location in one call to be able to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

To replace value directly in the `DataFrame`, use the `inplace` argument.

```
df.replace('columnvalue', np.NaN, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) or [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas.DataFrame.mask):

```
df = df.where(df != 'N/A')
```

or

```
df = df.mask(df == 'N/A')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try these snippets.

```
In [16]:mydata = {'x' : [10, 50, 18, 32, 47, 20], 'y' : ['12', '11', 'N/A', '13', '15', 'N/A']}
In [17]:df=pd.DataFrame(mydata)

In [18]:df.y[df.y=="N/A"]=np.nan

Out[19]:df 
    x    y
0  10   12
1  50   11
2  18  NaN
3  32   13
4  47   15
5  20  NaN
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this method fillna which pandas gives

```
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

first parameter is whatever value you want to replace the NA with.

By default, the Pandas fillna method returns a new dataframe. (This is the default behavior because by default, the inplace parameter is set to inplace = False.)

If you set inplace = True, the method will return nothing, and will instead directly modify the dataframe that’s being operated on.