# pandas valid null values

Tags: pandas, fillna

I am looking for the list of valid null values that pandas fillna() method will replace, e.g. 'NaN', 'NA', 'NULL', 'NaT'. I could not find it in the [documentation.](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/frame.py#L3029-L3035)

Comment: only NaN, NaT, and None values will be touched...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fillna` method will only replace actual missing values represented as `NaN` or `NaT` or `None` but not as strings ('NaN' or anyother string).
Before using `fillna` you can check what will be replaced in a column `COL` of your dataframe `df` using `isnull()`:

```
df.loc[df['COL'].isnull()]
```

will show you the subset of your dataframe for which the column 'COL' is `NaN`/`NaT`/`None`.

You can replace strings to `NaN` using `replace`. Say you have strings like "NAN":

```
from numpy import nan
df = df.replace('NAN', nan)
```

refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794067/how-to-set-a-cell-to-nan-in-a-pandas-dataframe)