# Turn NaN in dataframe if condition met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, filtering

I have a column here that looks like this and is part of a dataframe:

```
df.Days_Since_Earnings
Out[5]: 
0      21.0
2       1.0
4    1000.0
5     500.0
6     119.0
Name: Days_Since_Earnings, Length: 76, dtype: float64
```

I want to leave it as it is except I want to turn numbers above 120 to 'nan's, so it would look like this:

```
df.Days_Since_Earnings
Out[5]: 
0      21.0
2       1.0
4       nan
5       nan
6     119.0
Name: Days_Since_Earnings, Length: 76, dtype: float64
```

thanks to anyone who helps!

Comment: `df[df.Days_Since_Earnings.gt(120)] = np.nan`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a cell to NaN in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794067/how-to-set-a-cell-to-nan-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: `idx_days_over_120 = df["Days_Since_Earnings"] > 120` and then `df.loc[idx_days_over_120, "Days_Since_Earnings"] = np.nan`

Comment: this was helpful, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mask`:

```
df['Days_Since_Earnings'] = df.Days_Since_Earnings.mask(df.Days_Since_Earnings > 120)
```

or `where` with reverse condition

```
df['Days_Since_Earnings'] = df.Days_Since_Earnings.where(df.Days_Since_Earnings <= 120)
```

or `loc` assignment:

```
df.loc[df.Days_Since_Earnings > 120, 'Days_Since_Earnings'] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['days'] = df['days'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x > 120 else x)
print(df)
```

Or

```
df[df['days'] > 120] = np.nan

    days
0   21.0
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
4  119.0
```

Comment: Using `apply` for this is likely to be very inefficient: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/1011724